# Dealing with javascript function which processes strings that include quotes

Tags: javascript, php, string

So, essentially I have a button being created in PHP, which runs a JavaScript function, for example

```
function CreateText(id, string){
  alert(id + '' + string);
}
```

So the PHPcode looks like this

```
echo "<img onclick='CreateText(3,\"$userinput\")'>";
```

Where user input is coming from a text box. But, whenever the user inputs a string which contains quotation marks, it throws an error.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I already tried escaping the string the php way by using the backslashes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create a valid Javascript literal inside an HTML attribute. For the Javascript, use `json_encode`, to make that a valid HTML attribute, use `htmlspecialchars`:

```
$onclick = sprintf('CreateText(3, %s)', json_encode($userinput));
printf('<img onclick="%s">', htmlspecialchars($onclick));
```

See http://php.net/sprintf, http://php.net/printf, http://php.net/json_encode, http://php.net/htmlspecialchars.